# Is it possible to round the edges of inner labels in Kendo Pie Charts?

Tags: kendo-ui, pie-chart, kendo-dataviz

I have inner labels in my pie chart, but they don't look good. Is it possible to round the edges of the label background?

[image: Pie Chart]